# Year View in Fullcalendar jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

I started a YearView in fullcalendar (derived from the basic 'MonthView', needed to display longer events such as school holidays), and I could use a hand if anyone is already familiar with the way events get displayed on a view.

1. Using the 'BasicEventRenderer', how do I populate the 'segmentContainer' for 'DayEventRenderer' ?
2. And when do I initialize the default start & end date for delimiting the active year ? (the starting month could be changed, and it'd be nice to be able to keep the highlight on the current month and the current day).

See my github fork at https://github.com/Paulmicha/fullcalendar

-> example file is https://github.com/Paulmicha/fullcalendar/blob/master/tests/year-view-test-01.html

---

[image]

Comment: Im unable to get the events in year view with the above code. Please help in regarding this!!

Comment: Is there any recent update?

Comment: There's already a fork for yearview: https://github.com/tpruvot/fullcalendar/releases

Answer (score 12, accepted):

FullCalendar Documentation: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/

Loading events as JSON: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/

Render event: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/

Render event example:

```
fc.fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
    'id': 1,
    'title': 'Test Event 1',
    'start': '2009-11-05T13:15:30Z',
    'end': '2009-11-05T13:30:00Z'
});
```

Limit the display of available months: [Fullcalendar limit the display of available months?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927744/fullcalendar-limit-the-display-of-available-months)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback ! I'll get back to it whenever I get some time.

Comment: @Paulmicha  - were you able to work something out in the end for this? its exactly what i was looking for :)

Comment: @paul Im unable to get the events in year view with the above code. Please help in regarding this!!

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively if you need year view something like this:
[image]

**You can install it via npm** https://www.npmjs.com/package/fullcalendar-year-view

Steps:

```
cd yourFileLocation
npm init (press enter)
npm i fullcalendar-year-view
```

To get lib files go to `yourFileLocation/node_modules/fullcalendar-year-view/dist/`

Or alternatively, you can use **[browserify](http://browserify.org/)** for your page

Include css & js lib files to your page

Finally use 'year' view

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'year,month,basicWeek,basicDay'
  }
  ....
```

Answer (score 2):

I think an alternative for your user interface would be [bootstrap-year-calendar](http://www.bootstrap-year-calendar.com/#Examples/). It allows you view whole years and place one/multiple values per day, BUT the values would only be visible on hover or click.

For my need, it did the trick.