# fullcalendar year view with resources

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

We have a requirement of building year view calendar with resources. But we are not able to do it as the focus of the event is not moving to other month and even the events are not binding at their respective positions. Could anyone provide the solution for building year view calendar with resources?

We have referenced this link in building year view calendar with resources:

http://tux.fi/~jarnok/fullcalendar-resourceviews/

Comment: Year view is a branch from the original FullCalendar, so there is no oficial support for it, some have tried to implement it, but i think with no success.

Comment: Try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54440994/2992286

Answer (score 4, accepted):

we have achieved it just by creating custom month property and iterating the calendar   12  times.we have created 12 divs. each div will bind one calendar.
Here is the code

```
        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();
           var calendar = new Array();

        for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            calendar[i] = $("div[id='calendar" + i + "']").fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right:'resourceDay,resourceWeek,resourceNextWeeks,resourceMonth'
                },
                defaultView: 'resourceMonth',
                firstDay: 1,
                editable: true,
                selectable: true,
                minTime: 8,
                maxTime: 16,
                monthno: i,  //custom property
                selectHelper: true,
                resources: [{ "name": "Resource 1", "id": "resource1" },
              { "name": "Resource 2", "id": "resource2" },
              { "name": "Resource 3", "id": "resource3" },
              { "name": "Resource 4", "id": "resource4" }
              ],
                events: [
            {
                title: 'Lunch 12.15-14.45',
                start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 15),
                end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 45),
                allDay: false,
                resource: 'resource1'
            },
            {
                title: 'Meeting',
                start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
                end: new Date(y, m, d + 4, 11, 00),
                allDay: false,
                resource: 'resource1'
            },
                {
                    title: 'All Day Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, 1),
                    resource: 'resource2'
                }
        ],
                dayClick: function (date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
                    alert(date);
                },
                select: function (start, end, allDay, jsEvent, view, resource) {
                    var title = prompt('event title:');
                    if (title) {
                        calendar[start.getMonth()].fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                    {
                        title: title,
                        start: start,
                        end: end,
                        allDay: allDay,
                        resource: resource.id
                    },
                    true // make the event "stick"
                );
                    }
                    calendar[start.getMonth()].fullCalendar('unselect');
                },
                eventDrop: function (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view) {
                    alert('event moved to ' + event.start + ' to ' + event.resource);
                },
                eventResize: function (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view) {
                    alert('event was resized, new endtime: ' + event.end);
                },
                eventClick: function (event, jsEvent, view) {
                    alert('event ' + event.title + ' was clicked');
                }                  
            });
        }         

 ---------------------------



<div id="mainContainer">

 <h2>Calendar Demo</h2>
  <div class="fc fc-ltr" id="calendar0" month="0" style="font-size:13px"></div>
  <div class="fc fc-ltr" id="calendar1" month="1" style="font-size:13px"></div>
  <div class="fc fc-ltr" id="calendar2" month="2" style="font-size:13px"></div>
  <div class="fc fc-ltr" id="calendar3" month="3" style="font-size:13px"></div>
  <div class="fc fc-ltr" id="calendar4" month="3" style="font-size:13px"></div>
  <div class="fc fc-ltr" id="calendar5" month="3" style="font-size:13px"></div>
  <div class="fc fc-ltr" id="calendar6" month="3" style="font-size:13px"></div>
  <div class="fc fc-ltr" id="calendar7" month="3" style="font-size:13px"></div>
  <div class="fc fc-ltr" id="calendar8" month="3" style="font-size:13px"></div>
  <div class="fc fc-ltr" id="calendar9" month="3" style="font-size:13px"></div>
  <div class="fc fc-ltr" id="calendar10" month="3" style="font-size:13px"></div>
  <div class="fc fc-ltr" id="calendar11" month="3" style="font-size:13px"></div>
  </div>
```