# Full year calendar view

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, all-in-one-event-calendar

I'm looking for a Jquery calendar where I can manage events and view availability dates. 
I would like to use something like [fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/), but in a year view.

I have tried Jquery UI datepicker but can't figure out how to implement on the event.

```
    $(function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 12,
    showButtonPanel: true
   });
 });
```

This image describes the functionality I need: [image]

Can anybody suggest a nice full year calendar where I can easily manage events and view availability dates?

Thanks in advance

Comment: May be the link can help you(I know the answer is too late).


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12478459/1509986