# Making year view like google calendar in full calendar v3

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

How to make year view in fullcalendar version 3.

I also try this 
[Year View in Fullcalendar jquery plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10949486/year-view-in-fullcalendar-jquery-plugin).

But I want to make it like google calendar year view.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'year,month,agendaWeek,agendaDay',              
    },     
    firstDay: 1,
    eventLimit:true,
    slotMinutes: 5,
    //ignoreTimezone: false,
```

Comment: You would start here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/custom-view-with-js . but it's a lot of work (including follow up maintenance to keep pace with changes to fullCalendar etc). If you really want to invest this time and effort, is suggest basing it on the new v4 of fullCalendar which is a total re-write with better support for this kind of thing (since all views are now plugins) and also will be the supported version for bug fixes, new features etc from now on. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-js  for the v4 version of the custom view docs. V3 is a dead end in comparison.