# how to disable previous month in Full Calendar Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I  want to disable previous month button from [full calander](http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.6.4/demos/selectable.html)

Current month is April. When i clicked on previous button then calendar is showing previous March month. should not be happened.

http://jsfiddle.net/6enYL/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title'
        },
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        editable: true
    });

});
```

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927744/fullcalendar-limit-the-display-of-available-months/2928185#2928185

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, I've modified your fiddle with [lewsid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53079/lewsid)'s answer, and it works.
http://jsfiddle.net/6enYL/1/

```
    jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    viewDisplay   : function(view) {
      var now = new Date(); 
      var end = new Date();
      end.setMonth(now.getMonth() + 11); //Adjust as needed

      var cal_date_string = view.start.getMonth()+'/'+view.start.getFullYear();
      var cur_date_string = now.getMonth()+'/'+now.getFullYear();
      var end_date_string = end.getMonth()+'/'+end.getFullYear();

      if(cal_date_string == cur_date_string) { jQuery('.fc-button-prev').addClass("fc-state-disabled"); }
      else { jQuery('.fc-button-prev').removeClass("fc-state-disabled"); }

      if(end_date_string == cal_date_string) { jQuery('.fc-button-next').addClass("fc-state-disabled"); }
      else { jQuery('.fc-button-next').removeClass("fc-state-disabled"); }
    }
});
```

Comment: For those using this in v2, please note, that in v2 the css classes are now `.fc-next-button` instead of `.fc-button-next`. Same applies for all button headers. +1 for great answer.

Answer (score 5):

Disable past dates and view starts from today

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    firstDay :moment().weekday(),
    viewRender: function(currentView){
        var minDate = moment();
        // Past
        if (minDate >= currentView.start && minDate <= currentView.end) {
            $(".fc-prev-button").prop('disabled', true); 
            $(".fc-prev-button").addClass('fc-state-disabled'); 
        }
        else {
            $(".fc-prev-button").removeClass('fc-state-disabled'); 
            $(".fc-prev-button").prop('disabled', false); 
        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

FullCalendar is not like a traditional DatePicker. There is no way to initially setup the start and end dates of what you want to show.

You have to attach to [viewRender](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs2/display/viewRender/) event and manipulate the calendar with logic of your own. So if the dates are less than what you want you attach a class to that tile of 'disabled' for example. And also disable the previous button your self. You also then have to re-enable the previous button on the next month. Thanks to this kind of API you build your own custom calendar, but it can take time.

FullCalendar is just a calendar. The rest is up to you.

[Here is an update based on Prasad19sara answer](http://jsfiddle.net/6enYL/2/) : http://jsfiddle.net/6enYL/2/

```
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title'         
    },
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,         
    editable: true,
    viewDisplay: function (view) {
        //========= Hide Next/ Prev Buttons based on date range
        if (view.end > endDate) {
            $("#calendar .fc-button-next").hide();
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $("#calendar .fc-button-next").show();
        }

        if (view.start < startDate) {
            $("#calendar .fc-button-prev").hide();
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $("#calendar .fc-button-prev").show();
        }
    }

});
```

**Please be aware that viewDisplay is deprecated and will no longer be used in V2**

Answer (score 1):

This is my simple solution.

Place this code in the renderView function (around line 368 in version 1.5.4)) before ignoreWindowResize--; near the end of the function.

```
var lammCurrentDate = new Date();
var lammMinDate = new Date( lammCurrentDate.getFullYear(), lammCurrentDate.getMonth(), 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
if (currentView.start <= lammMinDate){
    header.disableButton('prev');
} else {
    header.enableButton('prev');
}
```

Comment: thankx but sorry answer already clicked. i will appreciate your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

For those using the FullCalendar.io version 2, you may use the following code

```js
viewRender: function(view) {
 var now = new Date(); 
 var end = new Date();
 end.setMonth(now.getMonth() + 1); 
 
 
 var cal_date_string = view.start.format('MM')+'/'+view.start.format('YYYY');
 var cur_date_string = now.getMonth()+'/'+now.getFullYear();
 var end_date_string = end.getMonth()+'/'+end.getFullYear();

 if(cal_date_string == cur_date_string) { jQuery('.fc-prev-button').addClass("fc-state-disabled"); }
 else { jQuery('.fc-prev-button').removeClass("fc-state-disabled"); }

 if(end_date_string == cal_date_string) { jQuery('.fc-next-button').addClass("fc-state-disabled"); }
 else { jQuery('.fc-next-button').removeClass("fc-state-disabled"); }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

```
header:{
  left:   'title',
  center: '',
  right:  'today prev,next'
},
```

Just remove "prev"... http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/header/
in your options

Answer (score 1):

If you have looking for a more recent solution (v4-compatible), look for `validRange`

See documentation : https://fullcalendar.io/docs/validRange

Answer (score 0):

In version v2 simply set the header without the option.
Like this for example:

```
        header: {
            center: "title",
            right: "month,agendaWeek,agendaDay"
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    businessHours: {
        start: '10:00', // a start time 
         end: '22:00', // an end time 
         dow: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
         // days of week. an array of zero-based day of week integers (0=Sunday)
    },
    hiddenDays: [ 0, 6 ],
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    viewRender: function(view) { 
        var now = new Date();
        var end = new Date();
        end.setMonth(now.getMonth() + 2); 
        //========= Hide Next/ Prev Buttons based on date range
        if (view.end > end) {
            $("#calendar .fc-next-button").hide();
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $("#calendar .fc-next-button").show();
        }
        if (view.start < now) {
            $("#calendar .fc-prev-button").hide();
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $("#calendar .fc-prev-button").show();
        }   
    }
});
```