# How to assign Date to defaultDate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I posted the same question but did not get the answer, so I post the question again.

Here are two global variables.

```
var ri_startDate = "";
var ri_endDate = "";
```

I added the date values stored in DB to global variables.

(The format of the date retrieved from the DB is YYY-MM-DD.)

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'getSectionDate.do',
    data: {"ri_idx" : ri_idx},
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(resultData){
        $.each(resultData, function(key, value){
            ri_startDate = value.ri_startDate;
            ri_endDate = value.ri_endDate;

            $('#ri_startDate').val(ri_startDate);
            $('#ri_endDate').val(ri_endDate);
        });
        if(ri_startDate != null || ri_startDate != "" || ri_endDate != null || ri_endDate != "") {
            $('#calendarContainer').show(700,rerenderingFullCalendar);
            $('.doctorname2').hide(700);
        }
    },
    error: function(resultData) {
        console.log("resultData Error >> " + resultData);   
    }
});
```

Now that everything is done, I'm going to insert it into the defaultDate.

As follows:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultDate: moment(ri_startDate)                 
});
```

However, this will cause an error.

So I did the following.

```
$(function() {
    var moment_startDate = moment(ri_startDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
    var result_moment_startDate = moment_startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');

    console.log(result_moment_startDate);

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        defaultDate: moment(result_moment_startDate)                 
    }); 
});
```

What did I do wrong?

I can not find the reason. I've tested it in Google Developer Tools, but it works fine. (When you create it globally instead of inside a function)

How can I do what I want? I just want to add the query value (ri_startDate) from the DB to defaultDate.

If you run this on Google Developer Tools, it works.

However, when I write this code and run it, I get the following error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clone' of null at MonthViewDateProfileGenerator.DateProfileGenerator.buildRenderRange (fullcalendar.js:10447) at MonthViewDateProfileGenerator.BasicViewDateProfileGenerator.buildRenderRange (fullcalendar.js:12144) at MonthViewDateProfileGenerator.buildRenderRange (fullcalendar.js:14621) at MonthViewDateProfileGenerator.DateProfileGenerator.build (fullcalendar.js:10265) at MonthView.View.setDate (fullcalendar.js:3624) at Calendar.renderView (fullcalendar.js:9607) at Calendar.initialRender (fullcalendar.js:9534) at Calendar.render (fullcalendar.js:9470) at HTMLDivElement. (fullcalendar.js:12414) at Function.each (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)

How do I fix it? Because of this, progress can not be made.

Please help me.

Comment: have you tried setting it in the way `$.fullCalendar.moment('2014-05-01');` first.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam The error does not occur, but it does not run. (ri_startDate was 2018-03-01)

Comment: donot add it as an answer until it works correctly

Comment: one more thing, where in the code have you placed this line `$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultDate: moment(ri_startDate)                 
});` inside the success function ? there isnt tho i can see it there.

Comment: your `ri_startDate` is coming from the `ajax` call and you need to call the calendar inside the success function or create a function and call it from the `success` function and pass the `ri_startDate` as parameter to it you wont be able to acces it as the ajax returns after the rest code is executed , if you try to `console.log(ri_startDate)` before you call `$.fullCalendar.moment()` it wont have anything . which is causing it not to work

Comment: yes i am talking about the `success` function of `ajax`

Comment: I've called fullCalendar outside of an ajax-containing function.

Comment: Is it the best choice to call calendar when ajax succeeds?

Comment: its not that you need to always call the calendar after an ajax call but the default date which you are setting when trying to initialize the calendar is coming from an ajax response and thus forces you to call it after ajax , as the ajax call would return after the calendar has been loaded and the date wont be populated yet , hope you get it

Comment: Now I know. But I have a question. The forEach statement sets the values ​​of ri_startDate and ri_endDate set in the global variable. If so, can you call the value set anywhere in the function? @MuhammadOmerAslam

Comment: you mean`.each()` not `forEach` ? yes you are right you can access `ri_startDate` and `ri_endDat` in any other function you don't need to actually pass it as a parameter if it is a global variable, BUT only after the response has been received.

Comment: Oh right. each statement! I am a beginner and can not understand well with text. If you do not mind, can you give me an example?(" BUT only after the response has been received") I'm really sorry to bother you.

Comment: did you try to change your code in the way i showed you in the image, it SHOULD work, or i can look for a workaround to show an example

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam The `resultTodayMomentDate` value is set to January 2018, but the month in which the calendar starts is still set to today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per our discussion you are sending `January 2018` as the date to moment and assigning it to `defaultDate` and `January 2018` is not in a recognized `RFC2822` or `ISO` format. moment construction falls back to `js Date()`, which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non `RFC2822/ISO` date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release.

Please refer to [URL](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/) for more info. As your current problem is that you are unable to set default date to the desired one and if you provide the date in proper format as i described above you can set the calendar to any date in past or future see a demo below i am setting the calendar to `2015-10-10`

```js
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  defaultDate: $.fullCalendar.moment('2005-10-01')
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.8.0/fullcalendar.print.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.8.0/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.8.0/fullcalendar.js"></script>


<div id="calendar">
</div>
```

Comment: oh, I have just solved the problem, but I will also refer to what you wrote. Thank you very much: P

Comment: please check my answer.

Comment: One more question. The starting month is now set up for this, but you need to set it for the ending month.

Comment: Can I refer to this link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927744/fullcalendar-limit-the-display-of-available-months

Comment: you mean you want to use a range of `start` and `end` date only to be visible on the calendar ?

Comment: use `visibleRange` option see [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/visibleRange/)

Comment: Yes you can depending on the requirements there are several options that are applicable in different cases just go through the API you will find all the concerns.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem with the help of @Muhammad Omer Aslam.

ajax part :

```
     $.ajax
     ({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'getSectionDate.do',
        data: {"ri_idx" : ri_idx},
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(resultData)
        {
           console.log("resultData : " + resultData);

           $.each(resultData, function(key, value)
           {
              ri_startDate = value.ri_startDate;
              ri_endDate = value.ri_endDate;

              var a = JSON.stringify(resultData);

              $('#ri_startDate').val(ri_startDate);
              $('#ri_endDate').val(ri_endDate);
           });

           if(ri_startDate != null || ri_startDate != "" || ri_endDate != null || ri_endDate != "")
           {
             loadCalendar(ri_startDate, ri_endDate);
              $('#calendarContainer').show(700,rerenderingFullCalendar);
              $('.doctorname2').hide(700);
           }
        },
         error: function(resultData)
         {
            console.log("resultData Error >> " + resultData);   
         }
     });
```

loadCalendar function part:

```
function loadCalendar(ri_startDate,ri_endDate)
{
   var todayMomentDate = $.fullCalendar.moment(ri_startDate);
  var resultTodayMomentDate = todayMomentDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');       
   console.log("resultTodayMomentDate : " + resultTodayMomentDate);

    // fullCalendar 관련
   $('#calendar').fullCalendar
   ({

   });

   $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', resultTodayMomentDate);
};
```

This all works well.

Answer (score 0):

Tried something like this... I used it before on my code.

```
$( "#datepicker-14" ).datetimepicker({
 //format : 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm'
    viewMode: 'days',
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
    }, "date");
var dateNow = new Date();
var date= moment(dateNow).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
```

Comment: `$("#datepicker-14")` and `datetimepicker` What their mean?

Comment: Thats id from html. I was picking date from that html.

Comment: Does it act like `dateDefault`?

Comment: this var dateNow = new Date();  what pick the date of system by default. Date() function is js default function.